# how to have 2 divs next to eachother and only 1 scrolls when the page gets resized?

Tags: css, html

I currently have a setup like this:

```
-------------
|nav| data  |
|nav| data  |
|nav| data  |
|nav|       |
-------------
```

(nav = navigation; -,| = outline of the page)

When I make my brower window smaller I want it to look like this:

```
-----------
|nav|  dat|
|nav|  dat|      
|nav|  dat|
|nav|scrol|      
-----------
```

(scrol = scroll bar)
but what I get is this:

```
----------      OR      -----------
|nav| dat|a             |nav|
|nav| dat|a             |nav|
|nav| dat|a             |  data |
|nav| dat|a             |  data |
----------              -----------
```

the contents of my data does not stay within the boundaries of my page.

I want my scrollbar only in the 'data' div

I have tried all kinds of things using float, tables, overflow, position, ...
my current code:

```
<div >
     <div id="PlaceHolder" runat="server"  style='float:left;width:200px;'>

     </div>
     <div id="facet_results" style="float:left;width:900px;" >
          <table ID="tblResults">
          <table>
     </div>
</div>
```

this is ok but when my page width goes below 1100px the 'results' div ends up below the 'placeholder' div

Can anyone help with this?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0px; }
        #nav {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0; top: 0;
            background: #ffffaa;
            width: 200px;
        }
        #body {
            margin-left: 200px;
            background: #aaffaa;
            overflow-x: scroll;
        }
        #inside_body {
            width:900px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="nav">
        Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some
        Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some
    </div>
    <div id="body">
        <div id="inside_body">
            Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some
            Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: (hehe replying to nobody) This works but is there a way to do it without the position:absolute? because this make the nav div jump out of the page.

Comment: @gen what do you mean it jumps out of the page? it doesn't in my browser.

Comment: I have a div with a background around the nav and data. When I add the absolute position the background doesn't resize along with the nav's height anymore. Would this be a mistake in my css setup then?

Comment: @gen That is normal behavior, when you give #nav the absolute positioning it doesn't affect the normal flow of the page anymore. The only other option that I can think of is to use a `<table>` but that would not work either because `<td>` doesn't support `overflow: scroll`. You should think of a trick to stretch the bg to the height of the nav.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right. I guess I'll just have to forget it and go for a scroll bar across the whole page. Thanks for the replies :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you out: http://cameronmoll.com/archives/000892.html

Though its not the most descriptive about things but at least there is a link to page that has that hack in use http://tuscany.cssmastery.com/

**Edit2: http://jsfiddle.net/CV8kv/ Simplified and a little more specified to suit your needs.**

---

Edit: Maybe i misinterpreted you example's.

Do you want the content area width to change when browser window decreases?

---

If not check this out http://jsfiddle.net/jzzgu/

Main point here is that you wrap your elements inside element ( in this case `<div id="wrap">` ) and then give that element width that is the main width of the site `#wrap { 600px; }` and when you put things inside that. Browser will take that as.. what it is.. and things inside that are not affected when you have bigger or smaller brow window.

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for. Yes I want the content width to change. In the example page you game I would want the 'Lavish Luxury, Unsurpassed Comfort' div to stay a set size and the div to the right of it to get smaller and when it's smaller than 900px a scrollbar should pop up inside that div (not in the navigation or across the entire page)

Comment: @gen Well, it was supposed to be more like a push to the right direction rather than word to word solution.

Check out my update.

Comment: I'm afraid that's still not the solution I want. But I have concluded that it's not going the work the way I want it to. Thanks though

Comment: @gen what is it that is missing?

Comment: if you check out nobody's answer that's what I'm looking for .. almost. More info the the comments there.